# SharePoint Lists and Microsoft Flow - Get new items only?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, microsoft-flow

I would like to create a Flow so that once a day I can export new list data from a SharePoint Online list into Smartsheet so that a dashboard can be displayed to managers with this data.

I have been able to setup the `Schedule` action just fine, and the actual import of data into Smartsheet action is fine, but the `Get Items` SharePoint action is pulling in all list items every time.

Will I need to setup an additional column/action to track if the item has been moved to Smartsheet already so that I can filter down the `Get Items` action?

Comment: Not answer, just a question : any specific reason to choose that approach over a search based approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a search based approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Filter array to filter the items.

For example: use `addDays(utcNow(),-1)` to filter Created greater than yesterday.

[image]